# Mediasoup_error logModern@main-f945abb9.bundle.js:1

Tags: node.js, video, camera, mediasoup

I'm putting an open code called hcw@home on my aws ec2 ubuntu server, but the problem is that mediasoup keeps loading infinitely, I inspected the page and it gave me this error

2024-02-02T16:06:37.773Z ERROR [main-aacc2dbb.bundle.js:1:370995] _joinRoom() [error:"%o"] Object
logModern@main-f945abb9.bundle.js:1

What do you think it could be?

I changed some settings but it didn't help, I wanted it to work...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.